# cant do my 10 reps

Tags: exercise, programs

My target is to get bulked

The problem is that sometimes when I increase weight I cant finish the 10 reps in the set, so I stop at 7 or 6.

Shall I reduce weight so I can finish the whole 10 or shall I stop at the number of reps I can do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another response says a basic principle of building mass is Progressive Overload which means increasing the volume of weight you lift at each session. 
However, increasing the volume of weight isn't only about increasing the weight.

In my opinion, you shouldn't only focus on getting my 10 reps, you need to take multiple things into consideration :

- Weight (are you lifting more than last time ?)
- Rest time (are you resting less than last time ?)
- Number of reps (pretty straight forward)

If one of those increase (with the others being equal) then it's progressive overload and you are on your way. The goal is to work more (even a little) each time you lift.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't make it past 6 or 7 than you have probably made a too big jump or you're not pushing yourself hard enough.

Try making smaller jumps, push yourself hard and see what happens. If you can't make it to 10 that is expected, but you should at least see improvements between workouts. If you do 6 in one workout, you should be able to do 8 or so the next workout.

Another variable to play  with is rest. How much do you rest between sets? For mass you should restrict the amount of rest to 30-60 seconds usually.

Answer (score 1):

Progressive overload is one of the basic principle of building muscle mass so not be able to reach the rep count you mention is not so important. Always start with a weight you can do and increase the volume in each session. Never jump so much be patient and that weight will be your warm up set if u keep doing and taking care of your diet.